# Ubuntu 10.04 updating openssl for apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, openssl, upgrade

My company's website is on an EC2 instance. The os is ubuntu 10.04. Currently we are using packages installed through apt-get. We have apache 2.2.14 and openssl 0.9.8k. After some security audit, I was told to update the version of openssl. The latest version of openssl on the 0.9.8 line is 0.9.8y. Is it compatible with apache 2.2.14 ? If so, Is it easy or at least possible to upgrade the openssl only ? I read it on somewhere that some people simply recommend to upgrade the whole os. Any comments ?

I did try to upgrade by downloading the tarball of

httpd-2.2.24 + openssl 0.9.8y

I installed them both under

```
/usr/local/apache2
/usr/local/ssl
```

I configured apache by

```
./configure --enable-modules=all --enable-mods-shared="all ssl" \
--with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/ --enable-ssl
```

the /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl does show 0.9.8y
but my web service shows apache 2.2.24 + openssl 0.9.8k
Any idea how to fix it ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you set `CFLAGS` & `LDFLAGS` also?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ldd /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd
```

> ```
>   ...
>   libssl.so.0.9.8 => /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
>   libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
>   ...
> ```

The libssl.so.0.9.8 is still found in /lib/ system directory by the loader, not /usr/local/ssl. So you need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running httpd:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib && /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd
```

See also [this document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html) for more info on compatibility between apache & openssl. See [this table](http://upstream-tracker.org/versions/openssl.html) for info on binary compatibility of openssl 0.9.8k and 0.9.8y.

[image]